# Use C++17 features to better delete all pointers from a container

Tags: c++, refactoring, c++17

Before C++17, deleting all pointers from a map looked like:

```
for (TMapBuffOnAttrs::iterator it = m_map_buff_on_attrs.begin();  it != m_map_buff_on_attrs.end(); it++)
{
    if (NULL != it->second)
    {
        delete(it->second);
    }
}
m_map_buff_on_attrs.clear();
```

With C++17, we got:

```
for (auto it = m_map_buff_on_attrs.begin();  it != m_map_buff_on_attrs.end(); it++)
{
    if (NULL != it->second)
    {
        delete(it->second);
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: [Range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)? [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)? [Smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory#Smart_pointers)? Not using pointers at all?

Comment: `delete` handles null properly, so `if` is unnecessary. `()` after `delete` are unnecessary as well.

Comment: Foregoing the raw pointers could simplify quite a bit. Just saying.

Comment: Put `std::unique_ptr<type>` as the value in the map and the things will be deleted automatically. Another way: `for(auto& [key, value] : m_map_buff_on_attrs) delete value;`

Comment: _@Tamás Sipos_ You could get way better and more simplified answers if you would mind to show us what `TMapBuffOnAttrs` actually is.

Comment: the solution has been in c++ since day one: dont use pointers when you want objects

Comment: Btw, `auto` has been introduced in C++11, C++17 doesn't really bring something compared to c++11/c++14 here (smart pointer).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  typedef std::map <BYTE, CBuffOnAttributes*> TMapBuffOnAttrs;
  TMapBuffOnAttrs m_map_buff_on_attrs; I am developing an outdated game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

```
for (auto it = m_map_buff_on_attrs.begin();  it != m_map_buff_on_attrs.end(); it++)
```

Since you only use the value `*it` and no other data from that iterator, a for-range loop would be simpler.

```
if (NULL != it->second)
{
    delete(it->second);
}
```

Deleting `NULL` is well-defined and has no effect, this is a test you can skip.

---

Which gives:

```
for (auto& p : m_map_buff_on_attrs) {
    delete p.second;
}
```

---

Manipulating raw pointers is error-prone and makes you write more useless code. If `m_map_buff_on_attrs` were a map of smart pointers, your code would simply be:

```
} // m_map_buff_on_attrs goes out of scope and destroys and frees everything.
```

Comment: Thank you! what is the difference between delete and clear?
Missed the ".clear()" from the code!

Comment: @TamásSipos `clear()` on a container destroys the contained elements. In the case of raw pointers, only the pointer is destroyed, not what it points to. `delete` on a pointer does that. With a container of raw pointers, you need both. On a container of smart pointers though, `clear()` is enough since the destructor of the smart pointers destroyes the pointee.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 3):

RAII pattern is your friend:

```
using TMapBuffOnAttrs = std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Attr>>;

m_map_buff_on_attrs["attrName"] = std::make_unique<Attr>(x, a);


....
// loop is not needed, to delete just do:
m_map_buff_on_attrs.clear();
```

Comment: yes it is. In general it is recommended to use RAII pattern with anything. You may need to [take a look on that](https://youtu.be/JfmTagWcqoE).

Comment: One more thing, everything here is C++11, only `std::make_unique` is C++ 14.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for_each` with `lambda` function.

Here is a way:

```
std::for_each(m_map_buff_on_attrs.begin(), m_map_buff_on_attrs.end(), 
              [](auto &item) {delete item.second;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use smartpointers. And simply 'clear()' the container...
Otherwise this is just "C code written in C++17"

Comment: best smart pointer is the simplest smart pointer that suits your needs. It could be unique_ptr but you need to master move owhership or simply shared_ptr.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!